# Read custom JSON and fill data in XML

Tags: json, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, jsonparser

I need to parse a custom .json file like this:

```
 {"04 Device Name " : 
{
      "ECU_1":
      {
      "01 Diagnostic"        : "OK",
      "02 CAN Id"            : "123456789"
,
       "01 SoftwareVersion "     : {
       "01 DID" : "123456789",
       "02 Value " : "123456789"
      }
,
       "02 HardwareVersion "     : {
       "01 DID" : "123456789",
       "02 Value " : "123456789"
      }

}
}
```

into a custom .xml like this

```
<Component>
            <ECUShortName>ECU_1</ECUShortName>
            <LocationShortName>ECU_1_1</LocationShortName>
            <LocationAccessKey>[Protocol]UDS_CAN_D.[EcuBaseVariant]BC_F213.[EcuVariant]123456789</LocationAccessKey>
            <DiagnosticInfo>
                <DiagnosticInfoValue>123456789</DiagnosticInfoValue>
            </DiagnosticInfo>
            <CommunicationProtocol>UDS</CommunicationProtocol>
            <CommunicationState>8</CommunicationState>
            <DTCCount>
                <DTCCountValue>4</DTCCountValue>
            </DTCCount>
            <SWHWInformation>
                <Software>
                    <PartNumber>
                        <PartNumberValue>123456789</PartNumberValue>
                    </PartNumber>
                    <Version>
                        <VersionValue>17/38/00</VersionValue>
                    </Version>
                    <Category>2</Category>
                    <Supplier>
                        <Code>1234</Code>
                        <Name>Supplier_1</Name>
                    </Supplier>
                </Software>
                <Hardware>
                    <PartNumber>
                        <PartNumberValue>123456789</PartNumberValue>
                    </PartNumber>
                    <Version>
                        <VersionValue>15/44/01</VersionValue>
                    </Version>
                    <Supplier>
                        <Code>1234</Code>
                        <Name>Supplier_1</Name>
                    </Supplier>
                </Hardware>
            </SWHWInformation>
```

I could use almost any language, but cant think of one that suits best.
VisualBasic would be good for XML, JS for JSON.
But it isn't correctly formatted in JSON...

Do you have any idea, how this could be done?

Comment: There is almost no connection between the JSOn and the XML... Are you going to make up SupplierName, Category, VersionValue?

Comment: These are just examples. All Info is in the Json.

Comment: Questions should contain full and accurate input, output and expected samples. What kind of answer do you expect now?

Comment: Sorry, will do in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSLT 3.0 is pretty good for this. You can just write an XML-style template and populate it with values drawn from the JSON:

```
<xsl:variable name="json" select="json-doc('input.json')"/>
<Component>
    <ECUShortName>{$json?ECU_SHORT_NAME}</ECUShortName>
    <LocationShortName>{$json?Location?ShortName}</LocationShortName>
```

etc.

That's only a sketch, of course, because you've only provided a sketch of your actual data.